# Extend MasterPage in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I have a source code father JSP like that:

```
<table id="1" >
    <tr>
        <td>Table1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id=".insertCodeJSPInHere"></div>
<table id="2">
    <tr>
        <td>Table2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want when i extend father JSP in children JSP then children JSP like that

```
<table id="1" >
    <tr>
        <td>Table1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id=".insertCodeJSPInHere"><h1>YenDV</h1></div>
<table id="2">
    <tr>
        <td>Table2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I write in children JSP:

```
<div id=".insertCodeJSPInHere"><h1>YenDV</h1></div>
<%@include file="fatherJSP.jsp" %>
```

But it's not work. I don't understand? HELP!

Comment: You need to give more details on what you mean when you say it doesn't work. Do you see an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<jsp:include page="fatherJSP.jsp">
```

**The include directive:**

> `<%@include file="something.html" %>`
>
> Used for static imports like html pages

Comment: hey you. I want use like tag asp:Content  in ASP.NET. Are you know about this?